# Understanding $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]$ and other relevant concepts

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

This is a bit of a wall of text and so to clarify things I've put my questions in bold. I've always summarized my question in the final section so one could look at those and then look above for the context I've given, rather than having to read through this whole thing. My apologies this question is so long and a bit scattered but I suppose it represents my level of understanding (or really, lack thereof) on this topic. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

---

I'm currently working through the tail end of an abstract algebra $1$ course, so things like fields from rings, extension fields, polynomials and Galois Theory and one (likely simple) definition that I'm struggling with gaining the intuition for and seeing how to determine the value of is the notion of $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]$  where $\mathbb{K}, \mathbb{F}$ are field with $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{K}$ an extension field.

Now the book says to view this as the dimension of $\mathbb{K}$ when viewing $\mathbb{K}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. So, **to my mind that means determining the number of basis vectors for $\mathbb{K}$ over $\mathbb{F}$, correct?** Well, if that's correct then I seem to have quite a bit of difficulty doing just that for fields which are a bit more abstract than just your usual $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R},$ etc...

Consider, for example, the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3) \subset \mathbb{C}$. In the book this field is just given to us with the only reference to an object like this being the statement a few sections prior that

> Suppose we already have some extension field $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{L}$ and $\exists \beta \in \mathbb{L}$ which is a root of the irreducible polynomial $p \in \mathbb{F}(x)$ in $\mathbb{L}$. Let $\mathbb{F}(\beta)$ denote the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{L}$ containing both $\mathbb{F}$ and $\beta$.

Now given that then I would interpret $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ as the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3$ where the latter $2$ are roots in $\mathbb{C}$, correct? Based on some previous experience with the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a + b\sqrt 2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ I would interpret the elements of this field as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3) = \{ a + b\sqrt[3](3) + c\zeta_3 \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ since we can see $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in the field for $b=c=0$ and similarly for the other $2$ roots when their respective coefficients are the only nonzero ones. **Is this correct thinking for describing elements of these kinds of groups?**

The text, in the example referring to this group, casually says that "$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ is a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3))$ which is itself a degree $3$ extension over $\mathbb{Q}$" Which I imagine is referencing the number of basis vectors of the extension field when viewed as a vector space over the subfield. And then proceeds to say that $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3))][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3)): \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$$ Now I understand why the end value is $6$ when the intermediate values are $2$ and $3$ respectively, but **I don't understand how to see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3))] = 2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3)): \mathbb{Q}] = 2$**

Finally, the example goes on to say that the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $$\mathcal{B} = \{1, \sqrt[3](3), \sqrt[3](9), \zeta_3, \sqrt[3](3)\zeta_3, \sqrt[3](9)\zeta_3 \}$$ Which contradicts what I imagine the element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ to be since in my case the basis would just be $\{ 1, \sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3 \}$. So **How do I find the basis of fields of the form $\mathbb{F}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, ... )$?**

---

**Summarizing Questions**

1. How do I interpret fields of the form $\mathbb{F}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, ...)$?

   - Like in the example above $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$
   - Are these just the smallest subfield $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{L}$ that contains $\mathbb{F}, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, ...$ Where the greek letters denote roots of an irreducible polynomial $p \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ in $\mathbb{L}$? So that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}, \sqrt[3](3), \text{and}\ \zeta_3$ where $\sqrt[3](3), \text{and}\ \zeta_3$ are the roots of some polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ in $\mathbb{C}$?
2. How do I interpret the elements of such a field?

   - I always thought it was, say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a + b\sqrt 2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but that doesn't seem to track. Let alone for something like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3))$
3. How do I find the basis for these kinds of fields?

   - As above, the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3](3), \zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathcal{B} = \{1, \sqrt[3](3), \sqrt[3](9), \zeta_3, \sqrt[3](3)\zeta_3, \sqrt[3](9)\zeta_3 \}$ but interpreting this extension field in the way that I have I would have never got this as a basis.
4. Finally, is the value of $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]$ simply just the number of basis vectors when viewing $\mathbb{K}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: Use `\sqrt[3]{2}` to get $\sqrt[3]2.$ Parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Mostly the naive extension of what you wrote, up to two caveats: we need to account for linear dependence, and you need to include all powers of the thing you are adjoining. See, for example, Theorem 4 and Corollary 7 in Ch 13 of Dummit and Foote third Ed. We are essentially equation a field adjoined by an element with the field extended to a polynomial field mod the minimal polynomial of the adjoined element. 3) See #2, you get the basis by adjoining all the powers, 4) Yes

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, Thanks for the response. I am unable to access Dummit and Foote's book so if I may ask: What exactly is meant by "adjoining"? Are you just referencing the roots $\alpha, \beta, ...$ and saying that by "adjoining" them we are using them to define the smallest such subfield which contains them? And to try and understand a little better, taking $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$ as an example, the basis here is $1, \sqrt 2$ since $1 \cdot a + b\sqrt 2$ is a linear combination, and so how does taking linear dependence into account factor in here? And all powers of $\sqrt 2$ are just

Comment: for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $$(\sqrt 2)^k = 2^{\frac{k}{2}}$$ So that $\sqrt 2$ is still a basis element since any power of it is either a power of a rational number and hence a rational number (so covered by the $1 \cdot a$ part of an arbitrary element) or a power of $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: The linear dependency stuff relates to adjoining multiple elements which might be related by some algebraic equation and thus your resulting vector space is a little trickier to describe. If it's only one element you're adjoining then it's just adjoining the powers, yes. You can either bound the powers you need to add (say, via the degree of the minimal polynomial) or just add them in as necessary as you described in your prior comment. As another example, consider adjoining the third root of two to the rationals, which requires adjoining not only the third root of two but also its square

Comment: The key result which helps in finding dimensions is this: let $F\subseteq K$ be an extension of fields and let $\alpha\in K$ be a root of polynomial $f(x) \in F[x] $. If $f(x) $ is irreducible over $F$ and is of degree $n$ then $[F(\alpha) :F] =n$. Further a basis of $F(\alpha) $ over $F$ is $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}\} $.

Comment: Next is the tower theorem which says that if $K$ is a finite extension of $F$ and $L$ a finite extension of $K$ then $[L:F] =[L:K] [K:F] $. The proof of this theorem usually constructs a basis of $L/F$ from given bases of $L/K$ and $K/F$ and that technique is the most common one to find a basis.

Comment: Also the proper way to interpret a field like $F(a, b, c, \dots) $ is that the members of this field are rational functions of $a, b, c, \dots$ with coefficients in $F$. In simpler terms anything which can be constructed using the members of $F$ and $a, b, c, \dots$ using field operations is a member of $F(a, b, c, \dots) $. In special case when $a, b, c$ are algebraic over $F$ there is a way to express the elements of the field in a simpler form (like those in examples in your question).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the response! So, a basis of a field like $\mathbb{F}(a,b)$ over $\mathbb{F}$ would be something like $\{1, a, ... a^{n-1},b, ... ,b^{n-1},ab, ..., a^{n-1}b, ab^{2}, ..., a^{n-1}b^{2}, ..., a^{n-1}b^{n-1} \}$?

Comment: More generally if $K/F$ has basis $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\}$ and $L/K$ has basis $\{b_1,b_2,\dots, b_n\} $ then a basis for $L/F$ is the set $\{a_ib_j\mid i=1,2,\dots,m,j=1,2,\dots,n\}$. Your last comment is valid when $F(a) / F$ has dimension $n$ and $F(a, b) /F(a) $ has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume some familiarity with university level algebra. In particular that given a field $\mathbb{F}$ you know the polynomial ring $$R_n:=\mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\left\{\sum_{I\in\mathbb{N}_0^n}a_Ix^I: \text{for all but finitely many $I$ we have }0=a_I\in\mathbb{F}\right\},$$ where for $I=(i_1,\ldots,i_n)\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ we abbreviate the monomial $x^I=x_1^{i_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n^{i_n}$.

I will also only deal with finite, algebraic extension and provide only examples over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$, as this seems to be the specific context of the question.

1. $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ etc. are simply the "homomorphic images" of $R_n$ when you replace $x_1=\alpha$, resp. $x_2=\beta$ etc.
   Let's start slowely with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. We have $R_1=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_ix_1^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$. Replacing $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ we get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_i\sqrt{2}^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$. However we can write, e.g., $a_2\sqrt{2}^2=a_2\cdot 2=2a_2\cdot \sqrt{2}^0\quad$ or $\quad a_3\sqrt{2}^3=a_3\cdot 2\sqrt{2}=2a_3\cdot \sqrt{2}^1\quad$ or $\quad a_4\sqrt{2}^4=a_4\cdot 4=4a_4\cdot \sqrt{2}^0$ and so on and in a combined way, e.g., $$1\sqrt{2}^0+2\sqrt{2}^1+3\sqrt{2}^2+4\sqrt{2}^3+5\sqrt{2}^4=1\sqrt{2}^0+2\sqrt{2}^1+3\cdot 2\sqrt{2}^0+4\cdot 2\sqrt{2}^1+5\cdot 4\sqrt{2}^0=(1+3\cdot 2+5\cdot 4)\sqrt{2}^0+(2+4\cdot 2)\sqrt{2}^1=27+10\sqrt{2},$$ thus we do not get anything new, by letting $d\geq 2$. Thus it turns out, after some work, that
   $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_i\sqrt{2}^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^1b_i\sqrt{2}^i: b_i\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}=\{b_0+b_1\sqrt{2}:b_0,b_1\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
   Let's play the game with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Replacing $x_1=\sqrt[3]{2}$ we get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_i\sqrt[3]{2}^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$. However we can write, e.g., $a_3\sqrt[3]{2}^3=a_3\cdot 2=2a_3\cdot \sqrt[3]{2}^0\quad$ or $\quad a_4\sqrt{2}^4=a_4\cdot 2\sqrt[3]{2}=2a_4\cdot \sqrt[3]{2}^1\quad$ or $\quad a_8\sqrt[3]{2}^8=a_8\cdot 4\sqrt[3]{2}^2=4a_8\cdot \sqrt[3]{2}^2$ and so on and in a combined way, e.g., $$1\sqrt[3]{2}^0+2\sqrt[3]{2}^1+3\sqrt[3]{2}^2+4\sqrt[3]{2}^3+5\sqrt[3]{2}^4=1\sqrt[3]{2}^0+2\sqrt[3]{2}^1+3\sqrt[3]{2}^2+4\cdot 2\sqrt[3]{2}^0+5\cdot 2\sqrt[3]{2}^1=(1+4\cdot 2)\sqrt[3]{2}^0+(2+5\cdot 2)\sqrt[3]{2}^1+3\sqrt[3]{2}^2=9+12\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{2}^2,$$ thus we do not get anything new, by letting $d\geq 3$. Thus it turns out, after some work, that
   $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_i\sqrt[3]{2}^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^2b_i\sqrt[3]{2}^i: b_i\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}=\{b_0+b_1\sqrt[3]{2}+b_2\sqrt[3]{2}^3:b_i\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
   This game gets quite tough pretty soon. Set $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and look, e.g., at $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. In this case it turns out, that you get old stuff for $d\geq 4$. Explicitly:
   $$
   \alpha^4=
   ((\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2)^2=
   (2+2\sqrt{6}+3)^2=
   (5+2\sqrt{6})^2=
   25+20\sqrt{6}+24=
   49+20\sqrt{6}=
   (50+20\sqrt{6})-1=
   10(5+2\sqrt{6})-1=
   10(2+2\sqrt{6}+3)-1=
   10(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2-1=
   10\alpha^2-1=
   10\alpha^2-1\alpha^0.
   $$
   You should be able to verify this calculation as correct, but you probably do not have any idea, how one comes up with it: the key word is minimal polynomial and we leave it at that for the moment. It turns out (I've shown that you can discard any $d\geq 4$ and ask you to believe me that you cannot discard any $d\leq 3$) that
   $$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^da_i\alpha^i: a_i\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^3b_i\alpha^i: b_i\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}=\{b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+b_3\alpha^3:b_i\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
   So far we only "adjoined a single element", let's do an example where we adjoin two elements, e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. We have $R_2=\left\{\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^da_{i,j}x_1^ix_2^j: a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$. Replacing $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $x_2=\sqrt{3}$ we get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^da_{i,j}\sqrt{2}^i\sqrt{3}^j: a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$. By now it should be no surprise that we can cut down on $d$, anything with $d\geq 2$ can be simplified, e.g.:
   $\sqrt{2}^2=2\sqrt{2}^0,\quad$
   $\sqrt{3}^5=9\sqrt{3}^1,\quad$
   $\sqrt{2}^6\cdot\sqrt{3}^3=24\sqrt{2}^0\sqrt{3}^1$. It turns out that
   $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\left\{\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^da_{i,j}\sqrt{2}^i\sqrt{3}^j: a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^1b_{i,j}\sqrt{2}^i\sqrt{3}^j: b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}=\{b_{0,0}+b_{1,0}\sqrt{2}+b_{0,1}\sqrt{3}+b_{1,1}\sqrt{6}:b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
   With a bit of work, one can show that $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha).$$ So we see that the number of adjoined roots is not an invariant of a number field. Obviously, it might be simpler to compute in the representation $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ as opposed to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, but in principle there is no difference whether we choose one or the other: it's like in linear algebra, you can "choose different bases", the choice is irrelevant from an abstract point of view, but some bases might be easier to compute in.
   As a final example we look at $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\zeta_3)$. Again this is a homomorphic image of $R_2$ replacing $x_1=\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $x_2=\zeta_3$. Clearly $\sqrt[3]{3}^3=3\sqrt[3]{3}^0$ so we can cut down all degrees $d_1\geq 3$ when being confronted with $\sqrt[3]{3}^{d_1}$. The story for $\zeta_3$ is a bit different. $\zeta_3$ is, esentially by definition, a solution of the equation $x^3=1\Leftrightarrow x^3-1=0$. However there is a factorization of $p=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ involving only polynomials with coefficients in the base field $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $p$ is not irreducible. Thus by the zero divisor rule either $\zeta_3$ solves $p_1=x-1=0$ or it solve $p_2=x^2+x+1=0$. Clearly the solution to $p_1$ is $\xi=1\in\mathbb{Q}$ and since $\zeta_3\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $\zeta_3\neq\xi=1$. We are left with the second possibility: $\zeta_3$ solves $p_2=0$ or, after substitution, $\zeta_3^2+\zeta_3+1=0$. This leads to $\zeta_3^2=-1\cdot\zeta_3^0-1\cdot\zeta_3^1$. As a consequence we can cut down on any degrees $d_2\geq 2$ in $\zeta_3$. So the cut-off degrees for $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\zeta_3$ are $d_1=3>d_2=2$ and different. Combining everything, we have:
   $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\zeta_3)=\left\{\sum\limits_{i,j=0}^da_{i,j}\sqrt{3}^i\zeta_3^j: a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}, d\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^2\sum\limits_{j=0}^1b_{i,j}\sqrt[3]{3}^i\zeta_3^j: b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}=\{b_{0,0}+b_{1,0}\sqrt[3]{3}+b_{2,0}\sqrt[3]{3}^2+b_{0,1}\zeta_3+b_{1,1}\sqrt[3]{3}\zeta_3+b_{2,1}\sqrt[3]{3}^2\zeta_3:b_{i,j}\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
   By now you should have a host of examples to see what it means to have $\mathbb{F}(\alpha),\mathbb{F}(\alpha,\beta)$, etc. What I have shown is essentially a generative process. This does coincide with a subtractive process in spirit of "start with $\mathbb{C}$ and cut away everything, that is not necessary to accomodate the generators without loosing the field property". For now, I will not explain, why these two perspectives coincide. I think that the "generative approach" is much more enlightening in the beginning as the "subtractive approach".
2. I hope that the answer for 1. also answered 2. passing by.
3. Dito 2.
4. Yes, $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]=\dim_{\mathbb{F}\text{-vector space}}(\mathbb{K})$. From the different presentations above in the answer to 1. you should see:
   $$
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2, \quad
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3, \quad
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4, \quad
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4, \quad
   [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=6.
   $$

I hope that answers all your questions.

**Final remark:** You actually have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}]=3\cdot 2=6$. This works sometimes, but this is not true in general. Here is a "counter example":
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=8$, but $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4\cdot 4=16\neq 8$. The reason why such a product formula does not work out is that there is some "overlap" beyond $\mathbb{Q}$: $-1\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}^2=-\sqrt{2}=\left(i\sqrt[4]{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: Wow. This was the most comprehensive and helpful answer I've ever received on here. I can't begin to thank you enough @Thomas Preu for the work that you put into this. This was exactly the kind of answer I had hoped to receive but knew was too good to be true. I think I understand now how to construct these types of fields using the generative process you laid out. Tomorrow, when this question is available for bounty, I'll be awarding you the bounty because it's the least I can do to give you credit for such a great answer. You should consider writing textbooks if you haven't already!

Comment: The way you describe $F(\alpha), F(\alpha, \beta) $ works only when  $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic over $F$. The argument doesn't apply in cases like $\mathbb {Q} (\pi) $.